# Why does electron-builder include my whole project folder in app.asar?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

When I extract the app.asar inside the builded Mac app with:

```
npx asar extract app.asar destfolder
```

I can see that it includes mostly everything which is in my project folder.

How can I exclude the files from app.asar?

This are parts of my package.json: (because its too much code for stackoverflow)

```json
"directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources"
    },
    "extraResources": [
      "./content/**",
      "settings.json",
      {
        "from": "resources/icon.png",
        "to": ""
      },
      {
        "from": "resources/${os}",
        "to": "../"
      },
      {
        "from": "binaries/${os}",
        "to": "binaries",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

This is my project folder:

[image]

And this is the content of the builded app.asar file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to exclude every folder I dont want in the app.asar in the build section of the package.json like this:

```json
"build": {
"files": [
  "!binaries/**/*",
  "!mac-build/**/*"
],
```